# How to retrive all the data based on current month of all the weeks in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need to retrieve all records based on week.

Data could be like this:

```
array(
numberofweaks:5
weak_1 = [2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42]
weak_2 = [2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42]
weak_3 = [2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42]
weak_4 = [2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42]
weak_5 = [2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42, 2019-11-21 22:00:42]
)
```

A lot of references tried but none are working.

Tried this, not working:

```
$monthOfWeaks = DB::table("UserDetails")
    ->whereBetween('creationdate', [Carbon::now()->subWeek(4)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), Carbon::now()])
    ->get();
```

Please share your reference!!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: your question description is a little weak...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if by "weak" you are referring to the period of 7 days, the word is actually "week".

Then, you are using the method `subWeek(4)` on Carbon. This method doesn't receive any arguments (because it should be just one week), if you want to substract many weeks, use `subWeeks($int)` instead. Check [the docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub):

```
Carbon::now()->subWeeks(4);
```

Finally, you don't need to format the date, just pass the instance. So your query should look like this:

```
$data = DB::table("UserDetails")
    ->whereBetween('creationdate', [now()->subWeeks(4), now()])
    ->get();
```